# SSIS limit number of rows processed in XML Transform?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt, ssis

I am on a project requiring me to use SSIS (2005) XML Task to "flatten" out an incoming (actually many incoming) XML file and then import the newly created XML file into SQL Server.

I have completed many of the files but some of the delivered files are so huge that it is non workable in development mode to tweak the XSL file and then wait for a run to see if the desired "flattened" XML file was created.

Is there a way for the SSIS XML Task to limit the number of records that it processes or any way to limit this process for development?

Comment: How? I am navigating to the different levels in the provided input file to grab the data itmes that I need using xpath - but how would I limit the data that gets transformed into the new file with xpath?

Comment: You could create a small test file that you reuse.  After you are comfortable your system works, then you could use regular files to see how well they perform.

Comment: The file is just to big - we do not create this file - it comes from an outside source - much to big to load in editor.

Comment: @JimEvans I think the point of RU's suggestion is that you do not have to do development with the 'real' files. I believe he is proposing that you create a test suite of one or more small test XML files that are representative of the files you will actually load. You do development using the small files only and if your package loads them all successfully, then it is considered ready for production. If the package fails in production, you update your test cases and repeat the process until your test suite covers all conditions you need to test.

Comment: @Pondlife - true and that is a thought. My original question is still something I would like to know though - is there a way to limit the number of rows a transform produces? I will up point him one for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question first: No. There is no way for an XML task to limit the number of rows that pass through its transformation. It must consume the entire XML document passed to it in order to ensure it is valid.

Two workarounds:

Download the XML file and write a Script Task that opens the file and uses LINQ or XMLDocument capabilities to filter the XML document down to a more manageable number of elements, and then either save that document back to a temporary file place *or* store it to an SSIS Variable of type String.

Alternatively, you could also download the XML file and use SQL's OPENXML capabilities and FOR XML clause to return XML in an Execute SQL task to a variable and use that as your source. But the major downside with that is it's a lot trickier to open an XML Document, filter it, and return it in the same format.

Then just use that new file (or SSIS Variable) as the source in your XML Task.

Comment: I acctally ended up putting a script task in the SSIS package and used vb.net to do the transform - worked great and it took the SSIS limitation out of the equation.